# Realizar ciclo while a partir de una consulta MySQLi en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

el día de hoy he caído en el siguiente problema, estoy realizando un sistema de administración de alumnos en la cual los datos se almacenan en una BD de MySQL, pero al momento de querer listarlos todos, no consigo realizarlo, estoy utilizando la función mysqli_fetch_array(), también ya lo intenté con la función mysqli_fetch_assoc() y no consigo obtener los datos, alguien podría ayudarme? Les comparto mi código.

**conexion.php**

```
<?php

//Iniciar la conexion
$mysqli = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', 'contrasenia', 'stacatalina');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo("Error debido a ".$mysqli->connect_errno.' - '.$mysqli->connect_error.'\n');
}
return($mysqli);
?>
```

**veralumnos.php**

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conexion.php'); ?>
<?php
 //initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
    header('Location: errorPrivilegios.php');
}

$consulta = "SELECT nombres, appaterno, apmaterno FROM perfiles WHERE privilegios='Alumno';";
if($buscardatos = $mysqli->query($consulta)){
            $alumnos = $buscardatos->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $buscardatos->free();
    }

else {
        printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        $mysqli->close();
        exit;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center">Alumnos</h1>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <table width="80%" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="2" class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="20%" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h4 class="text-center">Matricula</h4></th>
        <th width="50%" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h4 class="text-center">Nombre</h4></th>
        <th width="30%" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h4 class="text-center">Acciones</h4></th>
        </tr>
        <?php while ($row_alumnos = mysqli_fetch_array($alumnos)) { ?>
      <tr>
        <th align="center" valign="middle" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo ($alumnos['nombres'].' '.$alumnos['appaterno'].' '.$alumnos['apmaterno']); ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><button class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span></button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span></button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span></button></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

El navegador me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\stacatalina\veralumnos.php on line 102
```

Alguien podría por favor ayudarme? Gracias.

**SOLUCIÓN PARA FUTURAS REFERENCIAS**

**veralumnos.php**

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conexion.php'); ?>
<?php
 //initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
    header('Location: errorPrivilegios.php');
}

$sql = "SELECT nombres, appaterno, apmaterno FROM perfiles WHERE 
privilegios='Alumno'";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center">Alumnos</h1>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <table width="80%" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="2" class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="20%" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h4 class="text-center">Matricula</h4></th>
        <th width="50%" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h4 class="text-center">Nombre</h4></th>
        <th width="30%" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h4 class="text-center">Acciones</h4></th>
        </tr>
        <?php while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) { ?>
      <tr>
        <th align="center" valign="middle" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo ($ver[0].' '.$ver[1].' '.$ver[2]); ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><button class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span></button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span></button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span></button></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqli_fetch_row "obtiene una fila de datos del conjunto de resultados y la devuelve como un array enumerado, donde cada columna es almacenada en un índice del array comenzando por 0 (cero)". Ahi lo aplique a tu código. Probalo y comenta.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conexion.php'); ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center">Alumnos</h1>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <table width="80%" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="2" class="table 
table-responsive table-hover table-striped">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <th width="20%" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h4 
  class="text-center">Matricula</h4></th>
    <th width="50%" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h4 
  class="text-center">Nombre</h4></th>
    <th width="30%" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h4 
 class="text-center">Acciones</h4></th>
    </tr>

 <?php
 //initialize the session
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
 session_start();
 }
  if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
 header('Location: errorPrivilegios.php');
}

$sql = "SELECT nombres, appaterno, apmaterno FROM perfiles WHERE 
privilegios='Alumno'";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ 

?>


  <tr>


   <td><?php echo $ver[0] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $ver[1] ?></td> 
   <td><?php echo $ver[2] ?></td> 

    <?php } ?>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><button class="btn btn-warning"><span 
  class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>&nbsp;<button class="btn 
 btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span></button>&nbsp;
 <button class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-
 circle"></span></button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-danger"><span 
  class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span></button></td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Vaya que me ayudó estaba queriendo sacar los datos de la variable equivocada. Muchas gracias me ayudó demasiado tu código, actualizo la pregunta con la solución como me quedó.

Answer (score 0):

Colócale al `fetch_array` "MYSQLI_BOTH"

Ejemplo:

```
($row_alumnos = mysqli_fetch_array($alumnos,MYSQLI_BOTH))
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).